# How to run the same script for 5 instances in batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that is running for only instance. now i need to run the same script for 5 instances. the below script is for single instance.

when i use the for loop, i was unable to loop for all the instances.

```
@echo off
pushd "G:\Lakshu\Documents ID and address proof_test" || goto :eof

For( int i=0; i<6;i++)
(
REM zip all files in the backup directory
FOR %%A IN (*.*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r "%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
FOR %%A IN (*.*) DO DEL "G:\Lakshu\Documents\Instance1" "%%A"
popd
)
```

Comment: I don't know where you got that for loop syntax, but it's not even remotely correct for batch loops.

Comment: @SomethingDark: It's was taken from C! In Batch it should be: `For %%i in (1,1,6) do (`. Also, the `popd` command must be placed _after_ the loop, not inside it. (Although I still don't understand what _"loop for all the instances"_ means... **`:/`**)

Comment: I think, by "instance" he means a certain file named _instance_i_ representing a record about certain tested activity or its presence. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know if it addresses your task, since your question is a bit unclear. It will archive to Backup.zip the entire content of your source folder, and delete all source files.

```
@echo off
pushd "G:\Lakshu\Documents ID and address proof_test" || goto :eof
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -df Backup.zip
popd
```